# Magento Track shipment link on order view page not showing

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am unable to get the link to show up on admin end! My client is very irked by it missing. Any ideas?

The file adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml has the following code:

```
 <?php  if ($_order->getTracksCollection()->count()) : ?>
                    <a href="#" id="linkId" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->helper('shipping')->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_order) ?>','trackorder','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>
                    <br/>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

adminhtml/default/**your_template_name**/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml‌​ also has the same code.

Comment: Are you using a template?  This could be located here: `adminhtml/default/**your_template_name**/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml`

Comment: I have the same file both in the template directory and default directory- as I was messing with it.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this one!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the program formerly written by another programmer was not uploading the tracking numbers from the warehouse to the correct location in admin. It was adding it to the comments but not to the Shipment section. Once I fixed some code in the program to add the tracking numbers, all issues related were solved. Feel free to contact me if you need some help.